# jQuery animate() vs addClass() to move an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

To move an element I could use jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

```
// for simplicity I omitted a lot of boiler code..

$("#box").animate({left: 100},{duration: 250});

// or addClass() with a CSS class for the box and moving: 

$("#box").addClass("move-box");
#box {
    transition: all 250ms linear;
}
.move-box { 
    left: 100; 
}
```

I know animate() has the limitation that the properties can only be single numeric values(unless you also import jQuery UI). So this question is about moving the box, which is a numeric value.

Would it matter which function to use? Are there differences in performance?

Comment: This is quite an open question. IMO don't use `left`.

Comment: Wouldn't animate just create the css? I guess the difference would be like 0.000001ms so yeha... i do'nt think it matters

Comment: To move a fixed div, it's quite normal to use top/bottom/left/right, whether it's a numeric or percentage.

Comment: I would assume applying a class would be the better performer rather than dynamically generating it with animate().

Comment: @user5014677 jQuery animate doesn't create a CSS class if i remember well it animates the element by changing its position. This provides a support for older browsers that don't understand CSS3, but it is less efficient

Comment: @Kaddath oh ok, good to know, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is really broad and it doesn't really matter what you're using in your case. Your animation is quite simple and won't use many resources to perform. I'd recommend though to use CSS animation most of the time. Here's why:

## Performance

CSS animation will be sharper, faster, and smoother if you use CSS animation. It is built in the browser and doesn't require additional calculation jQuery does. You can even see recent plugin such as sliders using CSS animations for those reasons.

## Control

CSS animation has better controls without the need to import additional libraries. The easing is easily manipulable with Cubic Bezier and you can animate, out-of-the-box, thing like colors, transform, etc...

## 3D animations

Animating 3D properties in CSS is a breeze. Performances will also be higher using CSS.

## Responsive

If you have different values for responsive, everything will be easier to manage with CSS. Simple media queries do the trick instead of bulky, messy Javascript conditions. Also, if your animation on applies on some screen sizes, you won't have to declare a function to reset the style on the HTML tag since CSS animation doesn't put style inside `style=""`; it is easily overridable.

---

The only advantage I see in using jQuery animation is that it's easier to setup. The keyword `'toggle'` is also nice and you need to be hackish to imitate it in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is a concern and your animation is triggered by adding a class, you can use vanilla Javascript to do so, which will outperform both JQuery methods listed above:

```
document.getElementById('box').classList.addClass('move-box');
```

`classList` is available in all modern browsers including IE10+.

Answer (score 0):

You use animate when ever you want to "Animate" and element as it emphasises. It lets you to do the animation with required speed but it also adds inline style attribute into the HTML tag which is not preferred if the animation is not a must. Adding class is smarter and less mess, also you can remove the class without a mark left behind. But animate has another future that is usefull than adding class, which is, You can add another function in the end of the animation. Whenever the animation stops you can fire another function but I mentioned above useless if you dont have to create a animation.